# Переопределить нажатие физических кнопок iPnone

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Я начинающий разработчик, пытаюсь писать приложение xamarin под ios ,столкнулся с задачей переопределить нажатие физических кнопок в своем приложении,пишу на с#, если кто владеет информацией как это реализовать помогите, найти решение не получается.

Задача такова: при клике на текстовое поле формируется текст "нажмите кнопку" и при нажатии кнопки громкости больше или меньше  формируется текст кнопка вверх или кнопка вниз, тем самым кнопка громкости работает в моём приложении как кнопка выстрела или смена оружия.

Answer (score 2):

[Официальные гайдлайны App Store](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) запрещают переопределение стандартных переключателей, включая переключатели громкости:

> 2.5.9 Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected.